# Arduino: Taking the first measurement of a constantly updating variable as a new variable without it updating

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to determine the flow rate of a water filtration system for a project, but can't figure out or find how to take the first volume measurement from a loop that's constantly checking and updating the volume measurement.

This is what I have at the moment for the section of code that is calculating the volume, but volume kept updating. Want "Finitial" to be the first reading from volume. ("checkDist()" was a premade function from the skeleton code we were provided):

```
TLIvolume = checkDist() * 25.4 * 15.24;
volume = 5890 - TLIvolume - 276.53;
Ffinal = 276.53;
Finitial = volume;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go too much into complexities, the easiest solution would be to make `Finitial` a global variable (declare it outside of the `setup` and `loop` function blocks).

Then, to make sure it's only written to once, instead of writing to it in the `loop` function, write to it at the end of the `setup` function (which only runs once, on startup)